# coordinates are recorded well in the data table but when I transform them with st_as_sf they are not converted well

Tags: geospatial, spatial

[data table plants_noFD coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLkPE.png)

[the resulting map with wrong coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLbHB.png)

So, my problem is that the Northing coordinates are placed close to the equator (< 1°N in decimal degres) instead of being in Northern Europe. The coordinates in the data table are correct but when I use st_as_sf function the coordinates are wrongly converted. My coordinates should place points in Finland.

St_as_sf comes from sf package and this function converts foreign object into an sf object aka a spatial feature https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/

```
points_plants_sf = st_as_sf(plants_noFD, coords = c("EASTING_EPSG3067", "NORTHING_EPSG3067"), crs = 3067)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = points_plants_sf)
```

instead of 65°N the northing coordinates are 0.0025°N

Comment: Can you add details please ? What is that `st_as_sf` function ? Where does this come from ? What library ? What should it do ?

Comment: St_as_sf comes from sf package and this function converts foreign object into an sf object aka a spatial feature